# How do I select the content in a specified cell from all rows in a Datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a text box search bar in my WPF application that displays records in a datagrid if they match the textbox content. The DataGrid has 2 cells- The first is a string and the second is an Int. I would like to retrieve the int values from the second cell in every row by clicking a separate search button. I unfortunately cannot seem to figure out how to accomplish this.

```
      string ID = (DataGrid.SelectedCells[1].Column.GetCellContent(0) as TextBlock).Text;
```

Comment: Any good with linq? You could do something like DataGrid.Select(r => r.ElementAt(1))

Answer (score 0):

**About Retrieve The Specific Cell**

The way to get the cell by row and colunm info:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11615729/12949439

You can use the `GetCell(int row, int colunm)` method which created by [@LPL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620360/lpl) in loops to get all cells in the `DataGrid`.

After you get all the cells, you can find the specific cell in them, and select it.

---

**About Select The Specific Cell**

The `DataGrid` has a `SelectionUnit` property, and you can set it into `DataGridSelectionUnit.SingleCell` then you can just select cell instead of select whole row.

And you can also use the `SelectedCells` property to get or set the selected cell(s).

And if you want the user can only select one cell, you can set `SelectionMode` property into `DataGridSelectionMode.Single`, so the user can not select multi-cells.

And for more infomation, you read the [MSDN document about DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8), [about DataGrid.SelectionUnit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectionunit?view=netframework-4.8), [about DataGrid.SelectedCells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectedcells?view=netframework-4.8), and [about DataGrid.SelectionMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectionmode?view=netframework-4.8).