# Iterate Rows in a WPF datagrid then pass row value into a method and style row accordingly

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, styles

I have a WPF datagrid with a datatable as its source. The datagrid contains an invisible column containing a rowID. What I need to be able to do is iterate through each row in the datagird, pull out the rowID and pass this to a `bool IsArchived( int rowID )` method. If this method returns true I would like to style the datagrid row in some way.

I have tried to implement the method as I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934529/how-to-loop-over-the-rows-of-a-wpf-toolkit-datagrid)

```
private void colorArchived( DataGrid grid , GX3MaterialSelectionData data)
        {
            var rows = GetDataGridRows(grid);

            foreach (DataGridRow row in rows)
            {
                DataRowView rv = (DataRowView)row.Item;
                int rowID = (int)rv.Row[1];
                data.IsArchived( rowID );

            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<DataGridRow> GetDataGridRows(DataGrid grid)
        {
            var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
            if (null == itemsSource) yield return null;
            foreach (var item in itemsSource)
            {
                var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
                if (null != row) yield return row;
            }
        }
```

But the line `var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;` is always returning null.

I would like to do as much of this as possibly programatically.

Please let me know if you require anymore information.

Comment: What did you try before asking? Please post if you did anything. If not you can expect downvotes and/or a closed thread.

Comment: Sorry lazy of me. Updated post.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a long one but I would use a style selector for this job,

I've setup the data grid in the following window as an example.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:RowStyleSelector x:Key="styleSelector"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" RowStyleSelector="{StaticResource styleSelector}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The style selector is defined in the code behind below, note that TestClass represents the objects that you're putting in to the grid.

The RowStyleSelector class will have it's SelectStyle method run once for every row added to your grid.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<TestClass> Items
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<TestClass>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<TestClass>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            Items.Add(new TestClass()
            {
                ID = i,
                Text = "Text for row " + i.ToString()
            });
    }
}

public class RowStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        TestClass targetIem = item as TestClass;
        if (targetIem != null)
        {
            // You can work with your data here.
            if (targetIem.ID == 0)
            {
                // Locate and return the style for when ID = 0.
                return (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("ResourceName");
            }
            else
                return base.SelectStyle(item, container);
        }
        else
            return base.SelectStyle(item, container);
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:
In response to the comment below, see the revised RowStyleConverter, you won't need TestClass.

```
public class RowStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        System.Data.DataRow targetItem = item as System.Data.DataRow;
        if (targetItem != null)
        {
            // You can work with your data here.
            if ((int)targetItem["IDColumn"] == 0)
            {
                // Locate and return the style for when ID = 0.
                return (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("ResourceName");
            }
            else
                return base.SelectStyle(item, container);
        }
        else
            return base.SelectStyle(item, container);            
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this example seems to be written for using a collection of custom classes as the datasource to the grid. I am binding my datagrid to a datatable object.

Comment: Instead of using TestClass it can be a DataRow that you inspect instead

Comment: Cheers matey I'll give it a go and let you know :)