# Extract information from datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF. I have a DataGrid with number of rows and columns. I need to extract the information in each row for each column; how can I do this? Pay attention that I need the information of all rows for all columns, not a selected row.

I populated the DataGrid dynamically along these lines:

```
public class person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
}

List<person> persons = new List<person>();
persons.Add(new person() { name = "john", lastName = "brown" });
persons.Add(new person() { name = "polly", lastName = "parker" });
persons.Add(new person() { name = "ann", lastName = "parker" });
persons.Add(new person() { name = "rebecca", lastName = "moosavian" });

dataGrid1.ItemsSource = persons;
```

And now I need to retrieve the name and lastName properties from this DataGrid after editing.

Comment: I think you can find the answer to your question in this thread [How to loop over the rows of a WPF toolkit Datagrid][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934529/how-to-loop-over-the-rows-of-a-wpf-toolkit-datagrid

Comment: I tested this before but how can I reach to name and last name of each row this code return a row not texts like name and lastName in row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you populate your data gird?

You must have some data source bound to your data grid (this is typically an ObservableCollection of CLR objects or some other type of collection)... your data is there, there is no need to extract anything.

The bottom line is that a data grid must have a data source, the data you see in the data grid  is there and no extraction is necessary.

Comment: yes I have a data source but if I change and edit the datagrid will this data source change according to edit?

Comment: Yes, you need to use the ObservableCollection and implement some sort of change notification either the INotifyPropertyChanged or better yet use one of many MVVM frameworks that typically have a base class from which all your ViewModel classes inherith and this base class implements change notification out of the box for you so you don't have to deal with that... Most populare are Caliburn Micro  and MVVM Light...