# WPF DataGrid Not Return DataGridRow

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, icollectionview

I am using DataGrid in WPF application, using for loop for retrieving DataGridRow one by one until last, currently I sort datagrid by help of `ICollectionView` after using `ICollectionView` my for loop is not working.

XAML markup:

```
<DataGrid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="GridTest"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" AreRowDetailsFrozen="True" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Header="SNo" Width="0.25*" Binding="{Binding Path=SNo}" CanUserResize="False" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="SalaryAmt" Width="0.25*" Binding="{Binding Path=SalaryAmt}" CanUserResize="False" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="0.20*" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" CanUserResize="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Width="0.30*" Binding="{Binding Path=Address}" CanUserResize="False"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace SortGrid
{
    public partial class TestDG
    {
        Dictionary<string, GridStructure> Dict1;
        ObservableCollection<GridStructure> List1 = new ObservableCollection<GridStructure>();
        private ICollectionView _currentView;
        _currentView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(List1);
        _currentView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SalaryAmt", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

        void DispatchTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dict1.Clear();
            _currentView.Refresh();
            GridColors(GridTest_TierColors, GridTest);
        }

        private void GridColors(Brush[] col, DataGrid Grid)
        {
            int colorind = 0;

            for (int rowind = 0; rowind < Grid.Items.Count; rowind++)
            {
                DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)Grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowind);

                if (row != null)
                {
                    // conditional formatting here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to give us more details. What are you trying to achieve? What exactly isn't working there? You say your "foreach loop isn't working" but I can't see any foreach loop as well. Please be more specific

Comment: Sorry Damascus it is my mistake, i m using for loop instead of foreach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/1934568/1706610

Comment: No FodderZone, its still not return a row.