# How to cast DataRowView to Framework Element?

Tags: c#, wpf, casting

I'm trying to cast my datarowview to a FrameworkElement? Does anybody know how to do this? Maybe any alternatives to my issue. I'm just trying to cast it to a framework element that way I can get it's position.

```
FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)DG1.Items[i];
```

Comment: any compile/runtime error?

Answer (score 0):

To summerize, it is not possible.

> Whenever data is displayed, such as in a DataGrid control, only one version of each row can be displayed. The displayed row is a DataRowView

[form msdn.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview(v=vs.110).aspx)

However, you might be able to get [DataGridRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridrow(v=vs.110).aspx) (a Control/FrameworkElement) from a DataRowView, if the ItemsSource of the DataGrid is set to a DataTable, by iterating through the rows of the DataGrid. For example, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1934568/5615980).

You can read about implicit/explicit/use defined type conversions, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx).